# Image to Hexidecimal Data Conversion in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, hex

Using Python I am trying to convert each pixel of a B/W image to hex and store it in a '.txt' file. I have to use C for my application so its easier to read from a text file then do the entire conversion in C code. I have tweaked some example code from online, but I am still not very experienced with using Python.

When I run my python script it only produces two hex values instead of eight. At first I thought this was from the image being B/W, but an RGB image should contain `0x000000` for black and `0xFFFFFF` for white.

Python Script

```
from binascii import hexlify
import re

hexValNew = ''
placeHolder ='0'

file = open('Frame2.txt', 'w') #Create txt file for data

with open('Frame2.png', 'rb') as f:
    binVal = f.read(1)
    while len(binVal) != 0:
        hexVal = hex(ord(binVal))
        hexValNew = hexVal[2:4] #Remove "0x" from hex() process
        hexValString = str(hexValNew)

        if len(hexValString) == 1:
            hexValString = placeHolder + hexValString
        print hexVal

        #print(hexValString) #Test Line
        file.write(hexValString) #Write adjusted hex value to txt file
        binVal = f.read(1)

file.close() #Close txt file
```

Section of ./a.out

> ff
>   00
>   62
>   26
>   e0
>   c4
>   a2
>   d7
>   c2
>   90
>   00
>   00
>   49
>   45
>   4e
>   44
>   ae
>   42
>   60
>   82

From what I understand, the value should be have eight digits returned and not just two.

Comment: You read bytewise and the hexadecimal value of a byte has one or two digits.

Comment: So for instance, if I take the first section of my a.out then the actual value of the pixel would be: 0xff0062? That still doesn't make sense though, the image is gray scale so there should be three repeating values like 0x4b4b4b otherwise it won't follow gray scale correct?

Comment: PNG format is compressed. To retrieve the raw data you can use a library like [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ImageMagick on Unix, you can do the following:

```
convert rose.png:[5x5] txt: | tail -n +2 | sed 's/[ ][ ]*/ /g' | awk '{print $1,$3}'
0,0: #414042
1,0: #634040
2,0: #B53D30
3,0: #A54845
4,0: #998886
0,1: #6A6674
1,1: #C0494A
2,1: #E4312B
3,1: #DB403F
4,1: #98936E
0,2: #77796F
1,2: #CA948B
2,2: #A94D43
3,2: #603D31
4,2: #405937
```

The format is column,row: hex.

You can redirect that to a file if you want. I am not a Windows users. But there are likely Windows equivalents of the Unix commands. If not, then you can parse the output from the txt:. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#txt

Comment: This ImageMagick tool is super helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you don't bother writing any Python at all, but instead just use **ImageMagick** in Terminal to convert any PNG, JPEG or other format file to NetPBM format see [Wikipedia description.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format)

Look specifically at PGM format starting with P2 (ASCII) or P5 (binary) format. It is very simple to read with C. So to convert a PNG image to PGM P2 (ASCII) format, in Terminal use:

```
magick input.png -depth 8 -colorspace gray -compress none result.pgm
```

and look at your file with any text editor.

To convert a JPEG file to PGM P5 (binary) format, use:

```
magick input.jpg -depth 8 -colorspace gray result.pgm
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open a PNG and treat the data as raw image data. For example, the first 8 bytes of a PNG are known as the PNG signature, which are always the same for every PNG.

You should use a library such as [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/) or [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) to open the image, get the image data, and write it out in raw to a file. It would be easier to make a raw file rather than a file of hex strings that you will have to parse again in your C program.