# Python image cropping without any external library

Tags: python, image-processing

Is there a way to read the pixel colours values of an image without using any external libraries?

Comment: What is the motivation for doing this please? And what are the constraints of the problem?

Comment: I need to process a set of images, bringing images to the same size.

Comment: My only constraint is to do this from scratch.

Comment: Libraries are designed, debugged, tested and improved over time. I would recommend you use them as you can *"see further standing on the shoulders of giants"* - **Isaac Newton**.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is way too broad for Stack Overflow to write image editing software for JPEG, PNG, TIFF, TGA, PSD, PPM, WEBP, BMP without using libraries.

Comment: I agree, it's difficult to do this without an external library. I just thought that maybe someone has already done such an implementation, of reading the pixel colour values, at least for one format and it's happy to share.

Answer (score 2):

If you really, really must do this in Python without using a library, your simplest option is to convert your images to [NetPBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm) format - PGM if greyscale, PPM if colour, PNM if RGBA.

You can do that with the **NetPBM** tools, or with **ImageMagick**, or `libvips`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55717116/2836621)

Then you can easily open the files with Python without libraries, see third example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60316138/2836621).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. You could read the bytes of the binary file and parse its bytes according to the image format you are facing. This is very time consumptive and error-prone and due to this, I would not recommend doing it.

Comment: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-read-bytes-from-a-binary-file-in-python this describes to read the bytes of a binary file in python, this http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html describes the bytes structure of a png file, You can read the bytes and match them with the described file structure to read the image